# Android lollipop timer (time duration) input

Tags: android, input, view, timer

I am developing an app for Android in which the user can input a time interval for a timer. I think that the best approach for the input view would be to try and be consistent with the Android clock app timer input view, but I'm not sure how can it be achieved. My question is, how should the android clock app timer input style be implemented? The two main important aspects of the style is the designated keyboard and the fact the the timer interval text (for example, "00:00:00") is updated after every single-digit input, rather than for a few digits at a time (just to make it clear, if the input would be "347", the timer text would be updated 3 times: "00:00:00" -> "00:00:03" -> "00:00:34" -> "00:03:47").

This is a link to what the Android clock app timer duration input looks like (unfortunately, I can't upload the image):

[An image of the Android clock app timer duration input](http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/192970-gallery/Countdown-timer.jpg)

I apologize if this question is somewhat basic, however I am quite a noob and I could not find relevant information online. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

May be a little bit late for you, but I needed the same control and so I've implemented a [time-duration-picker](https://github.com/svenwiegand/time-duration-picker) as an Android library providing an input control similar to the one in Lollipop's stock timer app. The control is available in three flavors:

1. standalone control
2. picker dialog
3. preference

It looks like this:

[image: Standalone control]
[image: Picker dialog]

The library is available as open source (MIT license) on [GitHub](https://github.com/svenwiegand/time-duration-picker).